# Proper Syntax for Cloud SQL 2nd GEN 5.7 IF Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7

The following IF statement is working for me in db-fiddle MySQL 5.7, but it is throwing an error in Cloud SQL 2nd GEN 5.7. What is the proper syntax for Cloud SQL?

**IF Statement Throwing the Error:**

```
IF col_name <> "UniqueId" AND col_name <> "ProjectId" THEN
 # DO STUFF
END IF;
```

**IF Statement in Context:**

```
the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH NEXT FROM col_names    
    INTO col_name; 

    IF done THEN
      CLOSE col_names;
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

IF col_name <> "UniqueId" AND col_name <> "ProjectId" THEN

 # DO STUFF

END IF;
END LOOP the_loop;
```

**Cloud SQL Error Message:**

"*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';> "UniqueId" AND col_name <> "ProjectId" THEN SET concatFields ' at line 32 (line 35, file "dbConn")*"

**Fiddle with Working Example:**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7N3ehFpJcLp5suTb964fnQ/39

Comment: I ran the db-fiddle that you provided in a Cloud SQL 2nd gen MySQL 5.7 database using MySQL workbench 8.0.18 without any issue. Could you please try the same and see if it works? Which method are you using at the moment to run this sql script?

Comment: @mgoya I am connecting through Google Apps Script suing Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking [google cloud sql](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Logical-Operators_57344671) logical operators, I could not find <> as logical not equal.

You can try to use

```
IF col_name != "UniqueId" AND col_name != "ProjectId" THEN
```

or as per document (but this one won't work in mysql)

```
IF !(col_name == "UniqueId") AND !(col_name == "ProjectId") THEN
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!